# how to redirect links without the hashtag # to the correct page with hashtag

Tags: html, ajax, .htaccess, url-rewriting, hashtag

On my site, I am loading content dynamically with Ajax, so the URLs are like www.internet.com/#/contact.php, or www.internet.com/#/home.php.

I have many links/pages on my site, so I want to do that with .htaccess.

How can I check, if there is **NO** hashtag in the URL and add directly after the domain name, or the hashtag without removing the rest of the URL?

So www.internet.com/home.php should be redirected to www.internet.com/#/home.php, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule (?!^#/)^(.+)$ #/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: thank you for that, i have modified a bit (added a / after #). how can i set the rewrite rule only for the URL in the address bar and NOT for the links on the page..?

Answer (score 0):

The value after the hashtag is not sent to the server, so you can't check for its presence in server-side code (e.g. `.htaccess`). You would need a script that runs in the browser to detect the presence of the hashtag.